# Fund contract address

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract test{

    function fundcontract(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        address(this).balance += _amount;
    }

    function getbalance()public view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function getcontractAddress() public view returns(address){
        return address(this);
    }
}
```

Hello i did this simple code try to figure out on how to fund contract i get error `Expression has to be an lvalue.`
this is just for learning purpose so if someone can explain in detail would be nice thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`address(this).balance` is read-only and can't be incremented. You should instead use a `require` or an `assert` statement to declare that the sent Ether value should be the same as the value of the given `_amount` param as follows:

```
function fundcontract(uint256 _amount) public payable {
    require(msg.value == _amount, "`msg.value` differs from `_amount`");
}
```

Comment: ir returns error when trying to deposit `msg.value` differs from `_amount`

Comment: Well that's what it's supposed to do. In reality, you don't even need the `_amount` input param. You simply need to define a function as payable, keep the function body empty, and simply give it any `msg.value` you wish to.